# Eclipse crash course for IntelliJ developer

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

I've been using IntelliJ for years now. Are there any good websites or books on Eclipse?

I don't need to know what absolutely every single tab and feature does. I just want to be immediately productive and then have some more references to look up later.

Comment: A the risk of going a bit off topic can I ask why you're switching to Eclipse?

Comment: Sure, 2 reasons. 1. Learning. 2. GAE documentation have eclipse references. Btw, i really enjoy IntelliJ, unplug the mouse, it's thrilling! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some good sources:

- [Eclipse Project Configuration](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-ProjectConfiguration.htm)
- [IntelliJ Eclipse Migration FAQ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/migration_faq.html)
- "[Questions about IntelliJ to Eclipse transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964116/questions-about-intellij-to-eclipse-transition)"

Add a "[IntelliJ style mappings for Eclipse](http://www.jroller.com/ervines/entry/intellij_style_mappings_for_eclipse)" and you are good to go.

The SO question "[Things possible in IntelliJ that aren’t possible in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239732/things-possible-in-intellij-that-arent-possible-in-eclipse)" can help you spot more quickly some differences that you need to take into account during your migration process.